# Xml to Csv Python Code too long

Tags: python, pandas

The code takes a very simple xml and converts it into a dataframe in csv file.

This is the Xml file

```
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Phones>
    <Date />
    <Prog />
    <Box />
    <Feature />
    <WIN>MAFWDS</WIN>
    <Set>234234</Set>
    <Pr>23423</Pr>
    <Number>afasfhrtv</Number>
    <Simple>dfasd</Simple>
    <Nr />
    <gt>6070106091</gt>
    <Reno>1233</Reno>
    <QW>3234</QW>
    <ER />
    <VR />
    <Use />
    <Dar>sdfsd</Dar>
    <age />
    <name1>sdfsfdfs</name1>
    <Sys>IVECO E.A.SY.</Sys>
    <aac>2019-05-29</aac>
    <time>02:00</time>
    <nuk name="This is some text" text_g="asadsdas" text_h="2">fsdfsfd3432fdf</nuk>
  </Phones>

</Data>
```

This is my code.
It works, it just gets way too long when I want to include all the children of the father **phones**. 
Looking for some help on how to shorter the code but it performing the same purpose.

This is the code

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

def getvalueofnode(node):
    """ return node text or None """
    return node.text if node is not None else None


def main():
    """ main """
    parsed_xml = et.parse("short.xml")
    dfcols = ['Date', 'Prog', 'Box', 'Feature', 'WIN']
    df_xml = pd.DataFrame(columns=dfcols)

    for node in parsed_xml.findall('Phones'):
        Date = node.find("Date")
        Prog = node.find('Prog')
        Box = node.find('Box')
        Feature = node.find('Feature')
        WIN = node.find('WIN')

        df = df_xml.append(
            pd.Series([getvalueofnode(Date), getvalueofnode(Prog), getvalueofnode(Box),
                       getvalueofnode(Feature), getvalueofnode(WIN)],  index=dfcols),
            ignore_index=True)


    df.to_csv("./export.csv")

main()
```

This is all the columns declared fro dfcols

```
dfcols = ['Date', 'Prog', 'Box', 'Feature', 'WIN',
          'Set', 'Pr', 'Number','Simple','Nr',
          'gt', 'Reno','QW', 'ER','VR', 'Use',
          'Dar','age','name1', 'Sys' 'aac',
          'time', 'nuk']
```

**Additional**

The element **nuk** has multiple attributes so each attributes gets its own column
Example

nuk_name, nuk_text_g, nuk_text_h

Comment: With *all the children of the father phones* - did you mean all tags within `Phones` parent tag having dataframe to declare 23 columns?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, yes that is what I meant.

Comment: You said "it just gets way too long when I want to include all the children" and that's the case of your concern. So you need to post the actual code where you attempted "to include all the children". That's 2 different cases - parsing a particular tags and parsing all the tags. Post or extend the code that is of concern.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, I didn't add all the code because it just was too long. Inside the for loop I want to go through all the tags and parse them. When I wrote all of them the code inside the for loop gets long

Comment: at least, show how did you define `dfcols` for all columns. Did you hardcode 23 names manually OR parse the 1st block to get dynamic column names? Post the fragment where you defined `dfcols` for all tags

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, I updated my question above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Optimization and restructuring

*Redundant and inefficient things*
The `getvalueofnode` function is unneeded: `text` attribute of a node will be `None` or string value. 
All intermediate dataframes are also unnecessary.
Avoid using `pd.Dataframe.append` method within any loop as it will create a copy of accumulated dataframe of **each** loop iteration.

*Namings*
Use a meaningful names for your functions and `if __name__ == '__main__':` *guard*.
I would suggest **`phones_to_df`** function name.

---

Assuming that the goal is to convert all `Phones` tags child nodes into dataframe records - all you need is collect a dictionaries of child nodes as `<el.tag: el.text>` mappings at once (+ special case for **`nuk`** tag, see below).
Note, that some `Phones` tags could have their children in different order. So a list of dictionaries provides a robust way to arrange columns to respective values.

See the concise optimized approach below:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as cET
import pandas as pd


def phones_to_df(fname):
    tree = cET.parse(fname)
    pd.DataFrame([{**{el.tag: el.text for el in list(phone)},
                   **{f'nuk_{k}': v for k, v in phone.find('nuk').items()}}
                  for phone in tree.iterfind('Phones')]).to_csv('export.csv', index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    phones_to_df(fname="test.xml")
```

---

After generating the expected `export.csv` file the resulting sample dataframe may look as below (I've tested on xml file with 2 `Phones` tags):

```
print(pd.read_csv('export.csv').to_string())

   Date  Prog  Box  Feature     WIN     Set     Pr     Number Simple  Nr          gt  Reno    QW  ER  VR  Use    Dar  age     name1            Sys         aac   time             nuk           nuk_name nuk_text_g  nuk_text_h
0   NaN   NaN  NaN      NaN  MAFWDS  234234  23423  afasfhrtv  dfasd NaN  6070106091  1233  3234 NaN NaN  NaN  sdfsd  NaN  sdfsfdfs  IVECO E.A.SY.  2019-05-29  02:00  fsdfsfd3432fdf  This is some text   asadsdas           2
1   NaN   NaN  NaN      NaN    ABCD     123    456        aaa    bbb NaN        1111   222   333 NaN NaN  NaN    rrr  NaN      wwww  TIMES E.A.SY.  2019-12-29  03:00        text ...  This is some text   asadsdas           2
```

Comment: thank you very much .  The only problem I'm having right now is with the element nuk. I would have liked to show all of its attributes like one column for nuk_name, nuk_text_g , nuk_text_h. Considering that is also important information and I need to have in the csv file

Comment: @ebe, You need to reflect your requirements in your main question so all the contributors could see all the conditions from the very start

Comment: @ RomanPerekhrest , I'm sorry that is my mistake. Already added. Would really appreciate if you would help me with park and then me marking this as answered so it would be helpful in case anyone is facing similar problem

Comment: @ebe, Ok, the update is ready, you may check

Comment: I marked the question as answered. thank you. I have on quick question. Is It possible to make so that I read from a folder that as xml files and parses them into one csv file?

Comment: @ebe, that could be a case for another CR question

Comment: I would post a question but CR is for code that already works and I can just aks how to read through multiple xmls. Can you help me ?

Comment: hello, can you please have a look at this , still struggling on how to read through multiple xml files using your code. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59501200/12325998

Comment: @ebe, But that question has already been answered.

Comment: if you look at the comment I have added a link to were the entire code answered is and it is not working for me. Considering that to give the path to a folder of xml files is given but then also the  name to a single xml file. Would really appreciate your answer there

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to improve upon this code. I'll go through each thing I found and show how to better implement a solution.

- `getvalueofnode()` is redundant. You're checking if something is not `None` but returning `None` if the object is `None`. Instead of using this wrapper function, it is far simpler to just use the value of `node.text`. So in this example, every instance of `getvalueofnode(node)` should be translated to `node.text` without consequence.
- From the comments, it seems like you have a list of columns you would like to add from the xml. This seems like an excellent case for a for loop-- provided you have a predefined list of the columns you would like to extract.
- I notice you are using two dataframes. Why? From what I can gather, it is simpler to only keep track of one dataframe and use that for the result.
- On the topic of dataframes, it is better to collect all your values first and then translate the array of arrays to a dataframe **at the end**. Using `df.append` is an expensive operation and is not preferred when adding one row at a time in a predictable manner like this solution. It is better to collect all the values first and then convert the whole 2D array to a dataframe.

With those points in mind and a few more Pythonic changes, here is what a cleaned up version should look like:

```py
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parsed_xml = ET.parse("xml_parsing.xml")
    dfcols = ['Date', 'Prog', 'Box', 'Feature', 'WIN']

    values = []
    for node in parsed_xml.findall('Phones'):
        values.append(map(lambda n: node.find(n).text, dfcols))

    df_xml = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=dfcols)

    df_xml.to_csv("./xml_parsing.csv")
```

Comment: thank you for your answers, Some really good points. I tried the code. It is created the columns but didn't get the data their carry. So it was empty besides the columns